# A problem with routes in laravel how do i create many action in routes?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm learning laravel from a video tutorial. In that video use a command for routes list
`php artisan route:list` then the command panel showing this list
[video route:list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Ai6.png)

but when I used this command showing only one action. How to create other action like that video ?
$ php artisan route:list

```
+--------+----------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI        | Name | Action                                     | Middleware |
+--------+----------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | posts/{id} |      | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index | web        |
+--------+----------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create resourece controller run `php artisan make:controller --resource or php artisan make:controller -r`